# .Net Core Combining Multiple PNGs

Tags: .net, .net-core

I'm just trialing some .Net core out and checking out how to merge some PNG's into one but I seem to have an issue where only the last loaded image is showing (The rest just show in pure white).

So, I'm trying to merge:

[image]
[image]

But getting:

[image]

Transparency is very important, and that's working OK.

This is .Net Core 3 on Mac

```
  int targetHeight = 1051; //height and width of the finished image
    int targetWidth = 1089;

    //be sure to use a pixelformat that supports transparency
    using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
    {
        bitmap.MakeTransparent();

        using (var canvas = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            canvas.Clear(Color.Transparent);

            var bm1 = new Bitmap("./components/1.png");
            canvas.DrawImage(bm1, new Point(0, 0));

            var bm7 = new Bitmap("./components/7.png");
            canvas.DrawImage(bm7, new Point(0, 0));

            canvas.Save();
        }

        bitmap.Save("ouput.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test on .NET Core 3 Mac, but with .NET Core 2 on windows, this works:

Nuget Package: System.Drawing.Common, 4.5.1

```
namespace ConsoleApp20
{
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Drawing.Imaging;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var head = new Bitmap("./head.png");
            var body = new Bitmap("./body.png");

            using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(body))
            {
                bitmap.MakeTransparent();

                using (var canvas = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    canvas.DrawImage(head, new Point());
                    canvas.Save();
                }

                bitmap.Save("./output.png", ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This code has the same effect, so I suspect this a problem with DrawImage on Mac. :(